# adapter_response in run_results.json always blank for dbt run in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am looking for the query_id and other snowflake metadata (rows returned, etc) from a dbt run.

I see that [adapter_response exists](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/artifacts/run-results-json#top-level-keys) in the `run_results.json` to return this stuff from a database, but I cannot find any examples of it and Snowflake never returns anything.

This is the same for both snapshots and models.

Is there some configuration setting I'm missing either in Snowflake or dbt?

Comment: Not exactly sure but it seems the sfqid is currently returned for cases where there is an exception in the dbt run on Snowflake. Please review this : https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/pull/2358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query_id` was only added to the `adapter_response` for Snowflake in adapter v1.1 (see [release notes](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/releases) and the [associated PR](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/pull/40)). You will have to upgrade to dbt-snowflake 1.1.0